# Get flag by country name in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker

I'm using this package to get the country and country code.
In the user's profile, there is a flag that represents his country, but I didn't find anything on how to get the flag or the country's flag in this package. Does anyone know of an endpoint or package that I can send the country's name as a parameter and get it the flag?
example:

countries/${united-states}
return "us"
with that acronym "use" I can use this package and get the flag.
https://pub.dev/packages/circle_flags/example

The first package I get the country and the code.
In the second package I get the flag, but the first endpoint just gives me the name and the code, it doesn't give me the abbreviation of the country "us" , "br" etc.

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance.
Below I left the screen of how the flag is stored to the user's profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your question & as per my understanding, while creating an account, you want to fetch the country code (with the help of [CountryCodePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker)) & later on, in the edit profile, you want to represent the country flag that you've got earlier, but this time using the [CircleFlag](https://pub.dev/packages/circle_flags).

I created a sample application where the CircleFlag shows the country selected from CountryCodePicker. In your case, you need to store the selected country in the Local DB or web server & it's a mandatory step.

Output video of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://www.veed.io/view/a64c5b3e-5590-4a78-8a10-d213894d35a2?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Source code:

```
import "package:circle_flags/circle_flags.dart";
import "package:country_code_picker/country_code_picker.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String countryCode = "IN";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleFlag(countryCode),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              CountryCodePicker(
                initialSelection: "IN",
                onChanged: (CountryCode value) {
                  countryCode = value.code ?? "";
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```